# Get the Mantissa of a Java BigDecimal

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal, mantissa

I want to do some simple math with some very small and very large numbers. I figured I'd start with BigDecimal:

```
scala> java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(54, 45) 
res0: java.math.BigDecimal = 5.4E-44
```

How do I then get the the mantissa? Either `54` or `5.4` would be fine.

Comment: Can you not div the number by 10 in a loop?

Comment: What should the "mantissa" be for 10 scaled by 3, versus 1 scaled by 2? Both represent 0.1, but `BigDecimal#unscaledValue()` returns a different result for instances constructed via `BigDecimal.valueOf(10, 3)` and `BigDecimal.valueOf(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigDecimal.unscaledValue()`:

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(54, 45);
System.out.println(bd.unscaledValue()); //prints "54"
```

The result of this method is a `BigInteger` since `BigDecimal` has arbitrary length decimal precision.

### Edit

Here's the cleanest way I found to get the other way (5.4):

```
  bd.scaleByPowerOfTen(bd.scale() + 1 - bd.precision());
```

This I've tested less but it should cover all cases.  It scales the number such that there is no decimal fraction (`bd.scale()`), but then scales back so that only one number is left of the decimal point (`1 - bd.precision()`).